# How to access GRUB 2 in a computer with only Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, recovery-mode

I want to start the Recovery mode on an Ubuntu-only machine. The problem is that machine seems to skip grub and boot directly into ubuntu (as it is the only OS installed.

How can I boot into the recovery mode (whether it is through GRUB or not)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[According to this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Editing_the_GRUB_2_Menu_During_Boot), holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while booting should bring up the GRUB menu. If the <kbd>Shift</kbd> doesn't work, repeatedly pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> may work.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter BIOS (normally F2) first and then exit choosing `EXIT WITHOUT SAVING` or similar, you will be prompted with the GRUB menu.

Comment: Well, I'll be, it worked!  +1

Answer (score -1):

I once, not in the purpose of getting into grub (actually I was measuring the time it takes for Ubuntu to boot), did this and successfully accessed grub menu:
Boot up your computer by pressing the power key
While it's booting, long press on the power key to turn it off (I am not sure if it is a very safe way to get into grub)
Turn it on again with the power key, and...
Voila! Here you are at the grub menu.
;) You're welcome!